# Why is my blacklisted token still allowing me to access an API in Django Rest Framework with Simple JWT?

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

In logout I blacklisted a token. But i can access a api using that blacklisted token. I used django restframework simple jwt and blacklist app for blacklisted token.

In settings.py i have my jwt settings like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ]
}

SIMPLE_JWT = {
    'ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
    'REFRESH_TOKEN_LIFETIME': datetime.timedelta(days=1),
    'USER_ID_CLAIM': 'id',
    'ROTATE_REFRESH_TOKENS': True,
    'BLACKLIST_AFTER_ROTATION': True,
    'TOKEN_BACKEND': 'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist.backends.BlacklistBackend',
    'BLACKLIST_TOKEN_CHECKS': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist.check_blacklisted_token',
    ],
}
```

In my views.py I am sharing two apis logout and hello api:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated
from rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication import JWTAuthentication
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

class LogoutAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        # Retrieve the user's refresh token from the request or any other means
        refresh_token = request.data.get('refresh')

        if refresh_token:
            try:
                print(refresh_token)
                token = RefreshToken(refresh_token)
                token.blacklist()  # Blacklist the refresh token
                return Response({'detail': 'Successfully logged out.'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            except Exception as e:
                return Response({'detail': 'Invalid refresh token.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response({'detail': 'Refresh token not provided.'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class HelloView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [JWTAuthentication]
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get(self, request):
            user = self.request.user
            return Response(f"Hello, {user.username}!")
```

When ever i hit the hello api with a token which is blacklisted and stored in DB, the api stills sends me the content.

Answer (score 0):

The refresh token is what is actually blacklisted, as it is impossible to manually expire an access token. depending on the `ACCESS_TOKEN_LIFETIME` value in `SIMPLE_JWT` settings it could take a bit before the current access token expires, and in turn, the blacklisted refresh token is then used to attempt to generate a new access token.

Also, check to make sure you have added both `rest_framework_simplejwt` AND `rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py` like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt.token_blacklist',
]
```

as leaving them out can cause issues like the one you describe that aren't immediately obvious or easy to debug.